# Is it disadvantageous to my research career in bioinformatics if my PhD work is mainly software development?

Tags: phd, code, bioinformatics

1. I am in the fourth year of my Ph.D. studies in bioinformatics. I have published two articles, one in my second year on the comparative genomics of a group of bacteria as a co-first author.
2. Since then I took up software development and published software for comparative genome analysis, assembled from the various programs I wrote for my first publication.
3. Later I generated a web resource of data from this software containing comparative genomics of thousands of bacterial strains. This may become one of my thesis chapters and another publication, hopefully.

So, the majority of my thesis would consist of software development without any direct clinical or experimental research.
Will that be a major concern for a future career in this field?
I am scared that I won’t be given research positions and become a programmer forever.

Comment: Ask your advisor. Nobody else can answer this question better.

Comment: My advisor is quiet confident that It won't be a problem. But opinions of unknown refrees may vary.

Comment: @blueText: Have you also asked this your advisor? In the fields I am familiar with, the referee reports (and the defense) are a formality and they won't say you don't pass if your supervisor says so (especially if the referees know your supervisor).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I am concerned more about postdoctoral career. Should I edit this question or ask another. I am scared that I won't be given research positions and become programmer forever.

Comment: @blueText: I edited your question accordingly and think it can be reopened now. Please see whether everything is still according to your intentions and [edit] again if necessary.

Comment: Knowing good programming practices and software development standards in bioinformatics is a SKILL not a hindrance. You used that skill on a relevant topic and probably have good knowledge about comparative genome analysis. In bioinformatics there are always people that are more "bio" and people that are more "computer science" focused, and people who swap between those depending on the needs of their current projects.

Comment: This question is more like a discussion rather than a yes/no answer. But, you are not the only person and there are many in such a dilemma. So, this is a perfectly valid and relevant question to ask. I have upvoted your question as a F*** *** to the assholes who go around and mark every question as off-topic.